# A nested double sum(to do with e?)

Tags: summation, factorial, convolution, exponential-sum

I’ve come across this nested double sum while doing an investigation but cannot seem to find a closed form for it.

$$1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{i!} \sum_{j=0}^i}{\frac{1}{j!}}$$

This is about the simplest form I can get it to. I’m pretty sure it converges, using wolfram, to about 4.8343.

Some notes; 
The closest I’ve managed to get is $e^{e-1}$, which is gotten when the top bound of the second sum is $\infty$ instead of $i$. 
I think this may be some sort of convolution but I’m not sure which/how to undo that, I’ve studied generating functions a bit but not come across something like this.
For reference, it came up in a certain polynomial I’m looking at, namely $(1-x)^2(1-x/2)(1-x/6)(1-x/24) \cdots$
where the roots are factorial numbers.

Comment: The sum is $e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Q(n+1,1)}{n!}$ where [gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammaregularized) appears. Maybe the “Marcum Q” function would work

Comment: Gamma regularised does sound about right for this, thanks, i’ll look into it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way of looking at this expression:

Let your sum be $s=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^i\frac{1}{j!}$. Then (summations are interchangeable because of absolute convergence):

\begin{align}
s & = \sum_{i\geq0,\ 0\leq j\leq i}\frac{1}{i!}\frac{1}{j!}=\sum_{j\geq0,\ i\geq j}\frac{1}{i!}\frac{1}{j!}\\
 & = \sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{j!}\sum_{i\geq j}\frac{1}{i!} \\
 & = \sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{j!}(e-\sum_{0\leq i\leq j}\frac{1}{i!}+\frac{1}{j!}) \\ 
 & = e^2-s+\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{(j!)^2} \\
\implies s & = \frac{e^2+\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{(j!)^2}}{2}.
\end{align}

So your sum $s$ has a closed form (elementary) expression if and only if $\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{(j!)^2}$ does. I am not personally sure if it does but I am guessing no, because Wolfram alpha tells me [it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%201%2F%28n%21%29%5E2%2C%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity) is the [modified Bessel function of first kind](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Besseli%20functions). Numerically, it equals approximately 2.2796. Therefore your sum evaluates to
$$
s\approx\frac{e^2+2.2796}{2}\approx4.8343.
$$
This matches your results.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I’ll look into that function, seems interesting